# C# .net 4.5 async delegate

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, c#-5.0, asp.net-4.5

This does not throw compile error, but why?

```
public async void DoSomething(object arg){ ... }

Action<object> myAnonActionDelegate = DoSomething;
```

Shouldn't "`DoSomething`" have a signature of type `Func<object,Task>` as opposed to Action? In fact "`DoSomething`" is not be assignable to `Func<object,Task>` delegate.

The question is why? Is my understanding about async keyword off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Shouldn't "DoSomething" have a signature of type `Func<object,Task>` as opposed to Action?

No - the method doesn't return anything. Look at the declaration - it's `void`, not `Task`. The `async` part is just for the compiler's benefit (and humans reading it) - it's not really part of the signature of the method. An async method must return either `void`, `Task`, or `Task<T>` - but the return type of the method really *is* just what you declare it to be. The compiler doesn't turn your `void` into `Task` magically.

Now you *could* write the exact same method body and declare the method as:

```
public async Task DoSomething(object arg){ ... }
```

at which point you *would* need to use `Func<object, Task>` - but that's a different method declaration.

I would strongly advise you to use the form returning `Task` *unless* you're using an async method to subscribe to an event - you might as well allow callers to observe your method's progress, failure etc.

Comment: No it should either returns an IAsynchResult or a Task, I don't know which's which but it gotta compile into something that indicates this method is an async method.

Comment: got it! Thanks Jon. I guess I was hoping and thought async would automatically wrap the return type inside a task.

Comment: @Alwyn, `async` method can't return `IAsyncResult`, it always has to return `void`, `Task` or `Task<T>`.

Comment: @svick Yeah it was my misunderstanding. It is all cleared up now.